# Is it possible to have DependOnService to depend on a service on another machine

Tags: windows-service

On one server I have a Windows service that is dependent on a Windows service on another server. Is it possible to set up a dependency like this?

Answer (score 1):

What you mean by setting up a dependency?  If you have a service that relies on a service on another server then you'll have to use something to monitor the status of the service that is relied on.

Assuming service 2 relies on service 1 running on it's server.  If service 2 fails when service 1 fails, then you can script a command to start service 1 and have that run when service 2 fails after 3 retries.

If service 2 doesn't necessarily fail, then you should use something like [Solarwinds](http://www.solarwinds.com) Application Performance Manager (expensive) or [IPSentry](http://www.ipsentry.com) (inexpensive) to monitor the status of service 1 and execute a start script if service 1 dies (or at the least e-mail/page you).

Comment: What I mean by dependency is the standard Windows Service dependencies - you can set up a service to run only if another set of services is running. But maybe this isn't possible across machines.

Comment: I don't believe it is with out of the box Windows.  The best I can suggest is something like IPSentry that can check if a service is running and based on that execute a script that starts another service.